# Reconstruct InnoSetup file with existing CompiledCode.bin

Tags: decompilation, unpacking

Is it possible to somehow re-compile/reconstruct Inno Setup file and use existing CompiledCode.bin ? I dont have the source of CompiledCode.bin and writing from scratch is not an option.

Basically what I am trying to do is open up a setup.exe that was made via InnoSetup and edit a few text files inside, then recompile/reconstruct. I dont need to touch the Pascal script at all just change a few lines in a .txt file.

Comment: Wouldn't it perhaps be easier to wrap your installer in another one which performs these adjustments _after_ the wrapped installer finished? Just thinking ...

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thats not an option as the txt files I want to edit are the ones that are used for information purposes during the installation (part of the installer). This is why I just need to adjust existing installer and I dont care about what Pascal script does, it can stay intact.

Comment: Fair enough, that makes sense then.